# Self normalizing maximal subgroup of a non solvable group

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be a finite non-solvable group and $H$ its maximal subgroup. Prove that if $H$ is solvable then $H=N_G(H)$
I think I found different ways to prove it but I don't know how to begin:
-if $N_G(H)=G$ then $H$ is not solvable;
-if $G/H$ is simple then $H$ is not solvable;
-prove that $G/H$ is not simple;
-prove that $G/H$ is abelian;

Comment: Hint: If $N_G(H)\neq G$ then what must it be?

Comment: Then $N_G(H)=H$ since $H$ is maximal

Comment: Right. So you are done.

Comment: Yes, I know. The point is that I don't figure out how to prove it

Comment: Prove what? This is the proof.

Comment: How I prove that $N_G(H)$$\neq$$H$?

Comment: That is your very first bullet.

Comment: I don't think it is proved yet. You have written down "if $N_G(H)=G$ then $H$ is not solvable", but you have not proved or explained that assertion.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain really good. I meant that these could be different ways to prove the statement. And the one you said if it is true, then the statement follows. But it hasn't proved yet

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline proof. Suppose that $N_G(H) \ne H$. Then $N_G(H)=G$, so $H \lhd G$. But $H$ is maximal in $G$, so $G/H$ has no proper nontrivial subgroups. Hence $G/H$ is cyclic of prime order, and so is solvable. Also $H$ is solvable, so $G$ is solvable, contradiction.

Comment: I'm not following you. Since $H$ is maximal and normal in $G$ then $G/H$ is simple, i.e. it has no normal nontrivial subgroups

Comment: The fact that $H$ is maximal means that there are no subgroups $K$ with $H < K < G$, so $G/H$ has no proper nontrivial subgroups at all. The only groups with that property are the cyclic groups of prime order.